# pgfgantt chart with weekdays and dates

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar, pgfgantt

What i have is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=1cm,top=1cm,%
bottom=1.5cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid]{42}
\gantttitle{Title}{42} \\
\gantttitlelist[title list options={var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x using "\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\y}"}]{5,6,0,1,2,3,4}{6}
\ganttgroup{x}{1}{42} \\
\ganttbar{l}{1}{3} \\
\ganttgroup{y}{1}{42} \\
\ganttbar{l}{1}{3} \\
\ganttgroup{z}{1}{42} \\
\ganttbar{l}{1}{3} 
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

But i want the dates of these shortnames also be printed, seperated by a comma each day. Just like for example: Sat, 17.11.12  .. . .. . . . . Fri, 23.11.12.
I searched a little but so much information seems like overwhelming. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to work

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,left=1cm,top=1cm,%
bottom=1.5cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\newcount\startdate
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{2012-011-03}{\startdate}

\protected\def\zzz{\ {\pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\numexpr\startdate\relax}{\year}{\month}{\day}\year--\month--\day\global\advance\startdate1}}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid]{42}
\gantttitle{Title}{42} \\
\gantttitlelist[title list options={var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x using "\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\y}\zzz"}]{5,6,0,1,2,3,4}{6}
\ganttgroup{x}{1}{42} \\
\ganttbar{l}{1}{3} \\
\ganttgroup{y}{1}{42} \\
\ganttbar{l}{1}{3} \\
\ganttgroup{z}{1}{42} \\
\ganttbar{l}{1}{3} 
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, man why is this latex stuff so complicated. There should be something like a "Microsoft Word for all latex packages".

Comment: I never managed to use Word:-)