# How to partially remove the `vgrid` in a `pgfgantt` diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

`pgfgantt` manual says one has to use `vgrid={draw=none}` to remove vertical lines of a grid. But, how can one restrict the removal to only a particular element? In particular, suppose a group and a bar like below.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{ganttchart}[
        x unit= 5mm,
        y unit title=0.7cm,
        y unit chart=0.9cm,
        vgrid={*1{dashed}},
        title height=1,
        bar/.style={fill=blue},
        bar height=1,
        bar top shift=0,
        ]{1}{2}

        \gantttitle{Time}{2}\\             
        \gantttitlelist{1,...,2}{1} \\
        
        \ganttgroup[/pgfgantt/group/.style={font=\bfseries}]{Level 1: ...}{1}{2}
        \ganttnewline[black]
        \ganttbar{Requirement 1: ...}{1}{1}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

What is the way to remove those parts of the `vgrid` residing at the scope of the group?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you correctly, but do you want to have no vertical lines in the first row (labelled "Level "), but only in the second (labelled "Requirement 1")? How about the following columns?

Comment: @JasperHabicht: Yes, that's exactly what I want. I basically need to remove all vertical lines of the first row, whatever columns it encompasses.

Comment: Then you can probably add the option `shorten <=0.9cm` to the `vgrid` style: `*1{dashed, shorten <=0.9cm}`, since you set `y unit chart=0.9cm`.

Comment: What if the desired line is in the middle of the chart?

Comment: Then, obviously you cannot use this approach ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that you only need to remove the `vgrid` from the first row, you could probably say `vgrid=*1{dashed, shorten <=0.9cm}`. However, if the row without the `vgrid` lines should be in the middle of the plot, this approach would not work.

I took inspiration from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400382/47927) that adds color to the backgroud of a row by adding a `hgrid`. So, you could use this approach and draw thick white lines over the `vgrid` everywhere you need it. You need to tell the `hgrid` option where exactly you want to have this line drawn:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    grouprow/.style={
      line width=\ganttvalueof{y unit chart},
      yshift=-0.5*\ganttvalueof{y unit chart},
      shorten >=.2pt,
      shorten <=.2pt,
      white
    },
    normalrow/.style={
      opacity=0,
    },
}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{ganttchart}[
        x unit= 5mm,
        y unit title=0.7cm,
        y unit chart=0.9cm,
        hgrid={*1{grouprow}, *2{normalrow}, *1{grouprow}, *1{normalrow}},
        vgrid={*1{dashed}},
        title height=1,
        bar/.style={fill=blue},
        bar height=1,
        bar top shift=0,
        ]{1}{2}

        \gantttitle{Time}{2}\\             
        \gantttitlelist{1,...,2}{1} \\
        
        \ganttgroup[/pgfgantt/group/.style={font=\bfseries}]{Level 1: ...}{1}{2}
        \ganttnewline[black]
        \ganttbar{Requirement 1: ...}{1}{1}
        \ganttnewline[black]
        \ganttbar{Requirement 2: ...}{1}{1}
        
        \ganttnewline[black]
        \ganttgroup[/pgfgantt/group/.style={font=\bfseries}]{Level 2: ...}{1}{2}
        \ganttnewline[black]
        \ganttbar{Requirement 3: ...}{2}{2}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]